# when I am selecting multiple checkbox for deletion...only last one checkbox is deleted ! means it can delete 1 data from a database

Tags: php, mysql

Below code !Gives me check boxes and a delete button, In input tag all check box have same name (check)!! There check box can be retreive from database with id .

Problem Is:: when I am selecting multiple checkbox for deletion...only last one checkbox is deleted ! means it can delete 1 data from a database.

url like -> http://localhost/demo/delete.php?check=10&check=13&check=14&submit=Delete

I need while I am selecting a checkbox more than 1 checkbox  ,check box datas is deleted from database ! Any one help me to overcome this problem thanks

1. index.php

   ```
   <?php
   $sql = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
   mysql_select_db('database_section', $sql);
   ?>
   <form name="checkbox" method="get" action="delete.php">
       <table>
           <tr>
               <?php
               $sql = "select * from data";
               $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
               {
                   ?>
                   <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo      $row['data'];?>
                   </td>
                   <?php
               }
               ?>
           <tr>
               <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete"></td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </form>
   ```
2. Now, In delete.php..code below...

   ```
   <?php
   $sql = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
   mysql_select_db('database_section', $sql);
   if ($_REQUEST['submit']) {
       $abc = $_GET['check'];
       $sql = "Delete from data where id=$abc";
       $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
       if (isset($result)) {
           echo "data deleted";
       }
       else
       {
           echo "not possible";
       }

   }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: In this url `http://localhost/demo/delete.php?check=10&check=13&check=14&submit=Delete` your `$_GET['check']` ever will be `14`

Comment: give me some suggesstion..how can i do

Comment: Change name="check" to name="check[]". See @citizenen answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use check box as an array holder. name it as check[] to hold all selected values. And on post you will get the selected  array list.

Now your $abc will be a array, use foreach in delete.php to get the checked ids.

Answer (score 1):

Change `name="check"` to `name="check[]"`

See more here: http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/php-checkbox-array-in-form-handling-multiple-checkbox-values-in-an-array.html

Answer (score 0):

```
[...]
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        ?>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['data']; ?>
        </td>
    <?php
}
?>
[...]
```